# How to manually set number of iterated items in parallel queries in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, parallel-processing, cypher, neo4j-apoc

**Setup:**
Two different servers in remote data-center running Neo4j 4.2.9 Enterprise. First one has about 80 GB RAM, second one is somewhat slower.

**Data:**
I'm executing a very complicated conditional path-finding based on apoc.path.SpanningTree for ~15 000 IDs divided between 8 macroregions. Heaviest part of query is blacklisted nodes in amount from dozens of thousands up to about 1 million nodes for different macroregions. Tracing path for one ID takes ~50 MB of memory and ~1 second on average (with some rare but heavy exceptions). Each macroregion could have from 10 to 3700 IDs for now, but the number is going to increase.

**Problem:**
I found a working solution to parallelize tracing of all IDs in a chosen macroregion with use of apoc.cypher.mapParallel function (also tried apoc.cypher.parallel which worked slower, and apoc.cypher.mapParallel2).
When I'm checking how my query is iterating through the list of IDs with call dbms.listQueries I can see in column "parameters" which and how many IDs are currently in work. Example:

{
"retries": 1,
"batchSize": 10,
"parallel": true,
"concurrency": 10,
"_": [
"1-6Q77E9J2",
"1-6Q7NXW2E",
"1-6QIZ9ECU",
"1-6QIZDA26",
"1-6QIZGTC7"
]
}

Thing is, I can't change the amount of IDs per iteration and don't quiet understand the logic of Neo4j about it. I've tried to increase batchSize and concurrency, tried to switch to apoc.cypher.mapParallel2 and set different values to partitions and timeout - no luck, the Neo4j planner always iterates the same amount of IDs.

Results of testing on two servers for different macroregions are in tables below.

**To put it shortly:**

- the longer is the list of iterable IDs - the more IDs are being iterated per batch
- server with better hardware takes about 2x more IDs per batch
- but speed increase is not that much significant

***Faster server***

| Macroregion | Total exec time,s | IDs per iteration | Total amount of IDs in macroregion | Avg exec time per ID, s/ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MW | 7,532 | 1 | 10 | 0,753 |
| NW | 569,955 | 3 | 906 | 0,629 |
| SI | 3239,69 | 10 | 3717 | 0,872 |
| FE | 1343,438 | 6 | 2354 | 0,571 |
| POV | 2459,619 | 10 | 3733 | 0,659 |
| CEN | 822,114 | 2 | 647 | 1,271 |
| SO | 1877,518 | 7 | 2531 | 0,742 |
| UR | 2273,111 | 5 | 1608 | 1,414 |

***Slower server***

| Macroregion | Total exec time,s | IDs per iteration | Total amount of IDs in macroregion | Avg exec time per ID, s/ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MW | 7,713 | 1 | 10 | 0,771 |
| NW | 654,403 | 2 | 906 | 0,722 |
| SI | 3511,782 | 5 | 3717 | 0,945 |
| FE | 1450,656 | 3 | 2354 | 0,616 |
| POV | 2784,704 | 5 | 3733 | 0,746 |
| CEN | 964,475 | 1 | 647 | 1,491 |
| SO | 2435,731 | 4 | 2531 | 0,962 |
| UR | 2651,325 | 3 | 1608 | 1,648 |

**Questions**:

1. How to override this and manually choose how many IDs will be iterated in parallel?
2. Why "batchSize" doesn't do anything with my query and what it stands for in that case?
3. If anyone knows the details, what is the logic behind this default behaviour of Neo4j planner?

===========================================

Here's the query code with some commentaries - it's lengthy, but the gist is simple: for each item in iterable list we get a path with numerous conditions, then take nodes with certain labels from resulting path, and, finally, search for a specific subpaths from chosen set of nodes. Results are returned as simple table.

```
//Preparation of Product_ID list for iterating over it
match (a:products)<-[:node_vif|node_vlan|node_range|node_interface|port_attach|serviced_by*1..2]-(n:node)
where a.product_id is not null and n.mr='MW'
with collect(distinct a.product_id) as pid_arr

//Parallelized loop for tracing every Product_ID.
call apoc.cypher.mapParallel("
//Preparation of blacklist for Spanning Tree.
with _ as pid
match (a:products)<-[:node_vif|node_vlan|node_range|node_interface|port_attach|serviced_by*1..2]-(n:node)
where a.product_id=pid
with pid,collect(distinct n.region_code) as rc
match (z:products)<-[:node_vif|node_vlan|node_range|node_interface|port_attach|serviced_by*1..2]-(zn:node)
where z.product_id is not null and z.product_id <> pid and zn.region_code in rc
with pid,collect(z) as other_pids,rc
unwind rc as rc_
with pid,other_pids,
apoc.text.format(
\"select string_agg(blacklist::text,',')::text as blacklist 
 from neo4j.blacklist_for_prod_id_trace 
 where region_code in (%s)
\",
[apoc.text.join(collect(distinct \"'\"+rc_+\"'\"),',')]
) as sql

CALL apoc.load.jdbc('tracer_test',sql) yield row
with pid,apoc.convert.toIntList(split(row.blacklist, ',')) as bl_id,other_pids
match (x) 
where id(x) in bl_id
with pid,collect(x)+other_pids as blacklist

//Preparation of variables for Spanning Tree
match (a:products)<-[:node_vif|node_vlan|node_range|node_interface|port_attach|serviced_by*1..2]-(n:node)
where a.product_id=pid
with a,blacklist,
//depth of search
       case 
        when n.mr='POV' and a.product_id_type='IN' then 2
        when n.mr='POV' and not a.product_id_type='IN' then 4
else 12 end as depth
//relationship filter
, 'ptp_vlan|v_ptp_vlan|vlan|to_port|v_to_port|to_port_mbh|to_port_bbn|to_port_msn|to_interface|to_interface_bbn|to_interface_msn|serviced_by|if_vrrp|upper|rt_import|rt_export|node_vrrp|node_vif|node_vlan|node_range|node_interface|port_attach|port_grouped|port_group_member' 
as rFilter
//node filter
, case 
        when n.mr='POV' and a.product_id_type='IN' and not n.type='ETH' then '>port|interface|vlan|vlan_range|/virtual_vlan|>l2service|/virtual_interface|/l3service|/node'
        when n.mr='POV' and not a.product_id_type='IN' and not n.type='ETH' then '/port|/interface|vlan|vlan_range|/virtual_vlan|>l2service|/virtual_interface|/l3service|/node'
        when n.mr='POV' and a.product_id_type='IN' and n.type='ETH' then '>port|interface|vlan|vlan_range|/virtual_vlan|>l2service|/virtual_interface|/l3service|/node'
        when n.mr='POV' and not a.product_id_type='IN' and n.type='ETH' then '/port|/interface|vlan|vlan_range|/virtual_vlan|>l2service|/virtual_interface|/l3service|/node'
        when n.mr in ['NW', 'MW'] and not a.product_id_type='IN' then '/port|/interface|vlan|vlan_range|/virtual_vlan|/l2service|/virtual_interface|/l3service|/node'
        when n.mr in ['SO','NW', 'UR'] and a.product_id_type='IN' then '/port|/interface|vlan|vlan_range|/virtual_vlan|l2service|/virtual_interface|/l3service|/node'
        when n.mr='SO' and not a.product_id_type='IN' then '/port|/interface|vlan|vlan_range|/virtual_vlan|>l2service|/virtual_interface|/l3service|/node'
        when n.mr='FE' and not (a)-[:rt_import|rt_export]-() then '/port|/interface|vlan|vlan_range|/virtual_vlan|/l2service|/virtual_interface|/l3service|/node'
        when n.mr='FE' and (a)-[:rt_import|rt_export]-() then '/port|/interface|vlan|vlan_range|/virtual_vlan|/l2service|/virtual_interface|/l3service|/node'
        when n.mr='CEN' then '/port|interface|vlan|vlan_range|/virtual_vlan|>l2service|/virtual_interface|/l3service|/node'
        when n.mr='SI' and a.product_id_type='IN' then '/port|/interface|vlan|vlan_range|/virtual_vlan|>l2service|/virtual_interface|/l3service|/node'
        when n.mr in ['SI','FE', 'UR'] and not a.product_id_type='IN' then '/port|/interface|vlan|vlan_range|/virtual_vlan|/l2service|/virtual_interface|/l3service|/node'
else '/port|/interface|vlan|vlan_range|/virtual_vlan|>l2service|/virtual_interface|/l3service|/node'
end as lFilter

//the search
call apoc.path.spanningTree(a,{relationshipFilter:rFilter,labelFilter:lFilter,minLevel:0,maxLevel:depth,blacklistNodes:blacklist}) yield path as q
with q,nodes(q) as nd
unwind nd as d
with d,q

//adding chains to Spanning Tree's results

//Block 1
with d,q,collect(distinct ID(d)) as d_arr
optional match (z:interface)-[r:upper|vlan|assign|assign_if|serviced_by|if_vrrp|rt_export|rt_import|to_interface|to_interface_bbn|to_interface_msn]-()
where ID(z) in d_arr
with q,count(distinct ID(r)) as r_count,collect(distinct ID(z)) as z_arr,z
optional match pa_i = (z)-[:upper|vlan|assign|assign_if|serviced_by|if_vrrp|rt_export|rt_import|to_interface|to_interface_bbn|to_interface_msn]-(f)
where ID(z) in z_arr and r_count <=6 and (not (f.product_id is null and toUpper(f.alias) =~ '.*(MGMT|MGNT|MANAGEMENT|OAM|MONITORING|(^|_|-| )RING($|_|-| |\d)).*') or f.alias is null) and (not (f.product_id is null and toUpper(f.description) =~ '.*(MGMT|MGNT|MANAGEMENT|OAM|MONITORING|(^|_|-| )RING($|_|-| |\d)).*') or f.description is null)
with f,q,pa_i,collect(distinct id(f)) as f_arr
optional match pa_i0_p = (g)<-[:to_port|v_to_port|to_port_mbh|to_port_bbn|to_port_msn]-(x)<-[:port_attach]-(n:node) 
where id(g) in f_arr and (not n.type in ['BTS','BSC','RNC','MME'] or n.type is null) and exists{match (z:vlan)-[:vlan]-(f)-[:to_port|v_to_port|to_port_mbh|to_port_bbn|to_port_msn]-()-[:vlan]->(zz:vlan) where toInteger(z.name)=toInteger(zz.name)}
with f,q,pa_i,pa_i0_p
optional match (f)<-[r:ptp_vlan|v_ptp_vlan|serviced_by]-()
with f,q,pa_i,pa_i0_p,count(distinct ID(r)) as r_count,collect(distinct ID(f)) as f_arr
optional match pa_i0_vs = (g)<-[r:ptp_vlan|v_ptp_vlan|serviced_by]-(x)-[:node_vlan|node_interface|pl_vvlan]-(n) 
where id(g) in f_arr and r_count <= 4 and (not n.type in ['BTS','BSC','RNC','MME'] or n.type is null) and (not (x.product_id is null and toUpper(x.alias) =~ '.*(MGMT|MGNT|MANAGEMENT|OAM|MONITORING|(^|_|-| )RING($|_|-| |\d)).*') or x.alias is null)
with q,pa_i,pa_i0_p,pa_i0_vs,x
optional match (x)-[r:upper|vlan]-()
with q,pa_i,pa_i0_p,pa_i0_vs,x, count(DISTINCT ID(r)) as r_count,collect(distinct ID(x)) as x_arr
optional match pa_i1 = (x)-[:upper|vlan]-(i)
where ID(x) in x_arr and r_count <=6 and (not (i.product_id is null and toUpper(i.alias) =~ '.*(MGMT|MGNT|MANAGEMENT|OAM|MONITORING| (^|_|-| )RING($|_|-| |\d)).*') or i.alias is null)
with q,pa_i,pa_i0_p,pa_i0_vs,pa_i1,i
optional match (i)-[r:assign|assign_if|serviced_by|if_vrrp|rt_export|rt_import|v_ptp_vlan]-()
with q,pa_i,pa_i0_p,pa_i0_vs,pa_i1,i, count(DISTINCT ID(r)) as r_count,collect(distinct ID(i)) as i_arr
optional match pa_i2 = (i)-[:assign|assign_if|serviced_by|if_vrrp|rt_export|rt_import|v_ptp_vlan]->(f)
where ID(i) in i_arr and r_count <=3 and (not (f.product_id is null and toUpper(f.alias) =~ '.*(MGMT|MGNT|MANAGEMENT|OAM|MONITORING|(^|_|-| )RING($|_|-| |\d)).*') or f.alias is null) and (not (f.product_id is null and toUpper(f.description) =~ '.*(MGMT|MGNT|MANAGEMENT|OAM|MONITORING|(^|_|-| )RING($|_|-| |\d)).*') or f.description is null)
//Path summation
with q,pa_i,pa_i0_p,pa_i0_vs,pa_i1,pa_i2
with reduce(acc=[q],t in [val in [pa_i,pa_i0_p,pa_i0_vs,pa_i1,pa_i2] WHERE val is not null] | acc + t) as trc_i_
unwind trc_i_ as trc_i
with trc_i,nodes(trc_i) as nd
unwind nd as d

//Block 2
with d,trc_i
optional match (d)-[:serviced_by|vlan|assign|assign_if]-(vif:virtual_interface)<-[:node_vif]-(n:node)
where not n.type in ['BTS','BSC','RNC','MME'] or n.type is null
with vif,trc_i
optional match (vif)-[r:serviced_by|assign|assign_if|rt_import|rt_export|if_vrrp|serv_vrrp]-()
with count(distinct ID(r)) as r_count,collect(distinct ID(vif)) as vif_arr,trc_i
optional match pa_vif = (z:virtual_interface)-[:serviced_by|assign|rt_import|rt_export|if_vrrp|serv_vrrp]-(x)
where r_count <= 5 and ID(z) in vif_arr and (not (x.product_id is null and toUpper(x.alias) =~ '.*(MGMT|MGNT|MANAGEMENT|OAM|MONITORING|(^|_|-| )RING($|_|-| |\d)).*') or x.alias is null) and (not (x.product_id is null and toUpper(x.description) =~ '.*(MGMT|MGNT|MANAGEMENT|OAM|MONITORING|(^|_|-| )RING($|_|-| |\d)).*') or x.description is null)
with trc_i,pa_vif,x
optional match (x)-[r:upper|vlan|if_vrrp|serv_vrrp|rt_export|rt_import|assign|assign_if|serviced_by]-()
with trc_i,pa_vif,x, count(DISTINCT ID(r)) as r_count,collect(distinct ID(x)) as x_arr
optional match pa_vif_i = (x)-[:upper|vlan|if_vrrp|serv_vrrp|rt_export|rt_import|assign|assign_if|serviced_by]-(f)
where ID(x) in x_arr and r_count <=5 and (not (f.product_id is null and toUpper(f.alias) =~ '.*(MGMT|MGNT|MANAGEMENT|OAM|MONITORING|(^|_|-| )RING($|_|-| |\d)).*') or f.alias is null)
//Path summation
with trc_i,pa_vif,pa_vif_i
with reduce(acc=[trc_i],t in [val in [pa_vif,pa_vif_i] WHERE val is not null] | acc + t) as trc_vif_
unwind trc_vif_ as trc_vif
with trc_vif,nodes(trc_vif) as nd
unwind nd as d

//Block 3
with d,trc_vif
optional match (d)<-[rv:v_ptp_vlan]-(:vlan)
with d,trc_vif,count(distinct ID(rv)) as rv_count,[val in collect(distinct ID(d)) where 'virtual_vlan' in labels(d)] as d_arr
optional match pa_vv=(z)<-[:v_ptp_vlan]-(v:vlan)
where ID(z) in d_arr and rv_count <= 4 and (not (v.product_id is null and toUpper(v.alias) =~ '.*(MGMT|MGNT|MANAGEMENT|OAM|MONITORING|(^|_|-| )RING($|_|-| |\d)).*') or v.alias is null)
with trc_vif,pa_vv,v
optional match (v)<-[r:node_vlan|vlan]-()
with trc_vif,pa_vv,v,count(distinct ID(r)) as r_count,collect(distinct ID(v)) as vv_arr
optional match pa_vv_v = (v)-[:node_vlan|vlan]-(n)<-[:port_attach|node_interface|node_vif|to_node*0..2]-(:PL)
where ID(v) in vv_arr and r_count <=5 and (n.type is null or not n.type in ['BTS','BSC','RNC','MME'])
//Path summation
with trc_vif,pa_vv,pa_vv_v
with reduce(acc=[trc_vif],t in [val in [pa_vv,pa_vv] where val is not null] | acc + t) as trc_vv_
unwind trc_vv_ as trc_vv
with trc_vv,nodes(trc_vv) as nd
unwind nd as d

//Block 4
with d,trc_vv
optional match pa_v = (d)-[:ptp_vlan]-(v:vlan)<-[:node_vlan|v_ptp_vlan]-(n)
where (not n.type in ['BTS','BSC','RNC','MME'] or n.type is null) and (not (v.product_id is null and toUpper(v.alias) =~ '.*(MGMT|MGNT|MANAGEMENT|OAM|MONITORING|(^|_|-| )RING($|_|-| |\d)).*') or v.alias is null)
with n,trc_vv,pa_v,v
optional match (n)<-[rv:v_ptp_vlan]-(:vlan)
with n,v,trc_vv,pa_v,count(distinct ID(rv)) as rv_count,[val in collect(distinct ID(n)) where 'virtual_vlan' in labels(n)] as n_arr
optional match pa_v_vv = (n)<-[:v_ptp_vlan]-(x:vlan)
where ID(n) in n_arr and rv_count <= 4 and (not (x.product_id is null and toUpper(x.alias) =~ '.*(MGMT|MGNT|MANAGEMENT|OAM|MONITORING|(^|_|-| )RING($|_|-| |\d)).*') or x.alias is null)
with trc_vv,pa_v,pa_v_vv,n,v,x
optional match (x)<-[r:node_vlan|vlan]-()
with trc_vv,pa_v,pa_v_vv,v,x,count(distinct ID(r)) as r_count,collect(distinct ID(v)) as vv_arr
optional match pa_v_vv_v = (n)-[:v_ptp_vlan]-(x)-[:node_vlan|vlan]-(nn)<-[:port_attach|node_interface|node_vif|to_node*0..2]-(:PL)
where ID(v) in vv_arr and r_count <=5 and (nn.type is null or not nn.type in ['BTS','BSC','RNC','MME'])
with trc_vv,pa_v,pa_v_vv,pa_v_vv_v,v
optional match (v)<-[r:vlan]-(p:port)
with trc_vv,pa_v,pa_v_vv,pa_v_vv_v,count(distinct ID(r)) as r_count, collect(distinct ID(v)) as v_arr,v
optional match pa_v_p = (v)<-[:vlan]-(p)
where ID(v) in v_arr and r_count <=4
//Path summation
with trc_vv,pa_v,pa_v_vv,pa_v_vv_v,pa_v_p
with reduce(acc=[trc_vv],t in [val in [pa_v,pa_v_vv,pa_v_vv_v,pa_v_p] WHERE val is not null] | acc + t) as trc_v_
unwind trc_v_ as trc_v
with trc_v,nodes(trc_v) as nd
unwind nd as d

//Block 5
with d,trc_v
optional match pa_p = (d)<-[:to_port|v_to_port|to_port_mbh|to_port_bbn|to_port_msn|port_grouped|port_group_member*1..2]-(z:port)<-[:port_attach]-(n:node)
where d <> z and (not n.type in ['BTS','BSC','RNC','MME'] or n.type is null)
//Path summation
with case when pa_p is not null then reduce(acc=[trc_v],t in collect(distinct pa_p) | acc + t) else trc_v end as trc_p_
unwind trc_p_ as trc_p
with trc_p,nodes(trc_p) as nd
unwind nd as d

//Block 6
with d,trc_p,collect(distinct id(d)) as d_arr
optional match pa_q = (vr)-[:qnq]-(v:vlan)
where id(vr) in d_arr
//Path summation
with case when pa_q is not null then reduce(acc=[trc_p],t in collect(distinct pa_q) | acc + t) else trc_p end as trc_q_
unwind trc_q_ as trc_q
with trc_q,nodes(trc_q) as nd
unwind nd as d

//Final block
with d,trc_q
match pa_pl=(d)<-[:port_attach|node_vif|node_vlan|node_range|node_vrrp|node_interface|serviced_by*1..2]-(n:node)<-[:to_node]-(:PL)
where d <> n and not n.type in ['BTS','BSC','RNC','MME'] or n.type is null
//Path summation
with reduce(acc=[trc_q],t in collect(distinct pa_pl) | acc + t) as trc_pl
unwind trc_pl as path

//Getting specific nodes from resulting path
with nodes(path) as nd
unwind nd as d
match (d)
where any(x in ['PL','node','port'] where x in labels(d))
with collect(distinct id(d)) as list

//Matching specific subpaths
match (port1:port)<-[:port_attach]-(node1:node)<-[:to_node]-(pl:PL)
where 
ID(pl) in list 
and ID(node1) in list 
and node1.type in ['RRN','ETH'] 
and node1.mr='MW'
and ID(port1) in list 
and port1.port_type='ethernet' 
and not (port1)-[:to_port|v_to_port|to_port_msn|to_port_mbh|to_port_bbn]-(:port) 
with pl,node1,port1,list
match (pl)-[:to_node]->(node2:node)-[:port_attach]->(port2:port)
where  
ID(node2) in list 
and ID(node1)<>ID(node2) 
and ID(port2) in list 
and port2.port_type='ethernet' 
and not (port2)-[:to_port|v_to_port|to_port_msn|to_port_mbh|to_port_bbn]-(:port)
with pl,node1,port1,node2,port2,list
optional match (port1)<-[:port_attach]-(node1)<-[:to_node]-(pl)-[:to_node]->(:node)-[:port_attach]->(port3:port)
where id(port3) in list and port3<>port2 and port3<>port1 and not (port3)-[:to_port|v_to_port|to_port_msn|to_port_mbh|to_port_bbn]-(:port)
with pl,node1,port1,node2,port2,port3,list
optional match (port2)<-[:port_attach]-(node2)<-[:to_node]-(pl)-[:to_node]->(:node)-[:port_attach]->(port4:port)
where id(port4) in list and port4<>port2 and port4<>port1 and not (port4)-[:to_port|v_to_port|to_port_msn|to_port_mbh|to_port_bbn]-(:port)
with pl,node1,port1,node2,port2,port3,port4
match (port1)<-[:port_attach]-(node1)<-[:to_node]-(pl)-[:to_node]->(node2)-[:port_attach]->(port2)
where id(port3) is null and id(port4) is null
with distinct pl, node1, node2, port1, port2
match (pl)-[:at_region]->(:Region)-[:reg_mr_real]->(mr:MR)

return distinct node1.mr as mr, node1.region_code as region_code, mr.id_mr as id_mr, pl.name as pl,  node1.name as name_a, node2.name as name_b, node1.ip as ip_a, node2.ip as ip_b, port1.name as port_a, port2.name as port_b, COALESCE(node1.vendor,'EMPTY')  as vendor_a, COALESCE(node2.vendor,'EMPTY') as vendor_b
",
{parallel:true, batchSize:10, concurrency:10, retries: 1},pid_arr
) yield value

with value,size(pid_arr) as trn
return distinct value.mr as mr, value.region_code as region_code, value.id_mr as id_mr, value.pl as pl,  value.name_a as name_a, value.name_b as name_b, value.ip_a as ip_a, value.ip_b as ip_b, value.port_a as port_a, value.port_b as port_b, value.vendor_a as vendor_a, value.vendor_b as vendor_b,'iped' as search_type_a, 'iped' as search_type_b, 'Product_ID' as method_name, trn
```

Comment: Can you share your query? It will be tough to give useful advice otherwise

Comment: Sure, added the query to OP. I'm not very concerned about the query itself, but behaviour of apoc.cypher.mapParallel is what baffles me.